# Retaining Product Page Location and Pagination State in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pagination, algolia

I'm building a Next.js application with a product listing page that displays 12 products and includes a "load more" pagination button. The products are fetched from Algolia using server-side props. However, I'm facing an issue when users navigate to a product page and then click the back button. Upon returning to the product listing page, it resets to the top and only displays the first 12 products again.

To address this problem, my current solution involves moving the rendering logic out of server-side props and implementing a global context to store the number of products. When fetching the products, I use the global state to determine the number of products to return.

While my solution works, I would like to explore better alternatives or suggestions from the community. Is there a more efficient or effective approach to retain the user's location on the page and maintain the pagination state when navigating back from a product page?

I'm open to any recommendations or insights on how to enhance the user experience in this scenario. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think this is a very common issue with this sort of practice, have you thought about putting the page number into the url's query and maybe using pagination with a fixed number of items instead? This would retain the page on back navigation.